# How do I use the html element id in C#

Tags: c#, html, sql, getelementbyid

I am trying to use c# and SQL to count the number of times a link has been clicked on my webpage. So far I have html a link of this format:

```
`<a href="home.aspx" id="topNav-home" runat="server" onserverclick="clickCounter"><img src="img.png" /></a>`
```

I have a table(clickStream) in my SQL database that has a column 'linkName' and I would like to use the id to add 1 to the 'clickCount' column of the table. It would look something like this:

```
UPDATE clickStream
SET clickCount = clickCount +1
WHERE linkName = "htmlIdElement"
```

I already know how to connect to the SQL database using C#, but I have no idea how to get the value from the id element in the link to a state where it can be compared to the SQL column name. I have looked into using HAP(HTML Agility Pack) but was unable to make it work. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: I don't understand. You're asking how to get the element id of an element for which you specified the element id yourself?

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do. If you want to identify which link was clicked, the below suggestion about LinkButtons could work. I believe onserverclick relates to buttons, not links. You'll probably find it's being rendered direct to the HTML as it doesn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use html link better use asp link button and then on event you can get id

```
      <asp:LinkButton ID="topNav-home" runat="server" OnClick="clickCounter"><img src="img.png" /></asp:LinkButton>

protected void clickCounter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lbtn = (LinkButton)sender;
    string id = lbtn.ID;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a normal <a> tag I should use the asp:LinkButton?

Comment: yep it gives you much more controll

Comment: When I use a LinkButton I get a warning that 'href' cannot be used. How do I use the LinkButton as a hyperlink?

Comment: The new issue is that I cannot use an 'onclick' and 'postbackurl' with the linkbutton. If I include the 'postbackurl' it will link directly to the desired page, but will not execute my onclick method. Any suggestions?

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for all the Help! =]